# Getting "Duplicate entry '18' for key 'abc'", when abc is non-unique?

Tags: mysql

I'm on a replicated database, and on the original one everything was inserted ok, but on the replicated one I do get the following error:

```
"Duplicate entry '18' for key 'abc'"
```

This leaves me completely puzzled because:

```
mysql> show index from table;
+------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| table      |          1 | abc        |            1 | abc         | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

As clearly can be seen, this is a non-unique column... But somehow it has a duplicate entry??

Has anyone also encountered this error?

```
MySQL: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.30, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
OS: Debian GNU/Linux 6.0
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue, but haven't been able to fix it yet. I did read something about switching to "row-based replication", maybe that helps?

Comment: @Borniet This is already inside my configuration file: binlog-format=ROW -- So that'll not help...